# Best design pattern to control permissions on a "per object per user" basis with ServiceStack?

Tags: design-patterns, permissions, servicestack

I know that ServiceStack provides a RequiredRole attribute to control permissions, however, this does not fully work for my use case. I have a website with a lot of user-generated content. Users can only edit documents they have explicit permissions to. Permissions are controlled per object or group of the object. So, if a user is an admin of a group then they can edit all documents managed by that group.

What is the best design pattern to control access to a request on a `per object per user` basis? I want to approach this with as DRY a methodology as possible as it will affect 95% of all my API endpoints.

Also, can this be integrated with FluentValidation and return appropriate HTTP responses?

Many thanks,

Richard.

Comment: Richard did my answer help? Do you use a similar database schema? While your database design may vary I believe the filter attribute approach can be adapted to fix most access control designs, providing a DRY pattern. If you add details of your permissions control, I can tailor the answer better to your scenario. Thanks.

Comment: HI Scott, yes, your answer has been incredibly useful. Thanks so much for the obvious effort you made. I've been working my way through several techniques you highlighted and will give full feedback asap.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I use per object permissions in my ServiceStack applications. Effectively this is an Access-Control-List (ACL).

I have created a [Working Self Hosted Console Example](https://github.com/scottmcarthur/ServiceStackAdvancedPermissions) which you can fork on GitHub.

### ACL pattern:

I use the database structure shown in the diagram below, whereby resources in my database such as documents, files, contacts etc *(any resource I want to protect)* are all given an `ObjectType` id.

[image: Database]

The permissions table contains rules that apply to specific users, specific groups, specific objects and specific object types, and is flexible to accept them in combinations, where a `null` value will be treated like a wildcard.

### Securing the service and routes:

I find the easiest way to handle them is to use a request filter attribute. With my solution I simply add a couple of attributes to my request route declaration:

```cs
[RequirePermission(ObjectType.Document)]
[Route("/Documents/{Id}", "GET")]
public class DocumentRequest : IReturn<string>
{
    [ObjectId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Authenticate]
public class DocumentService : Service
{
    public string Get(DocumentRequest request)
    {
        // We have permission to access this document
    }
}
```

I have a filter attribute call `RequirePermission`, this will perform the check to see that the current user requesting the DTO `DocumentRequest` has access to the `Document` object whose `ObjectId` is given by the property `Id`. That's all there is to wiring up the checking on my routes, so it's very DRY.

### The `RequirePermission` request filter attribute:

The job of testing for permission is done in the filter attribute, before reaching the service's action method. It has the lowest priority which means it will run before validation filters.

This method will get the active session, a custom session type *(details below)*, which provides the active user's Id and the group Ids they are permitted to access. It will also determine the objectId *if any* from the request.

It determines the object id by examining the request DTO's properties to find the value having the `[ObjectId]` attribute.

With that information it will query the permission source to find the most appropriate permission.

```cs
public class RequirePermissionAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    readonly int objectType;

    public RequirePermissionAttribute(int objectType)
    {
        // Set the object type
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }

    IHasRequestFilter IHasRequestFilter.Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        // Get the active user's session
        var session = req.GetSession() as MyServiceUserSession;
        if(session == null || session.UserAuthId == 0)
            throw HttpError.Unauthorized("You do not have a valid session");

        // Determine the Id of the requested object, if applicable
        int? objectId = null;
        var property = requestDto.GetType().GetPublicProperties().FirstOrDefault(p=>Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ObjectIdAttribute)));
        if(property != null)
            objectId = property.GetValue(requestDto,null) as int?;

        // You will want to use your database here instead to the Mock database I'm using
        // So resolve it from the container
        // var db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection());
        // You will need to write the equivalent 'hasPermission' query with your provider

        // Get the most appropriate permission
        // The orderby clause ensures that priority is given to object specific permissions first, belonging to the user, then to groups having the permission
        // descending selects int value over null
        var hasPermission = session.IsAdministrator || 
                            (from p in Db.Permissions
                             where p.ObjectType == objectType && ((p.ObjectId == objectId || p.ObjectId == null) && (p.UserId == session.UserAuthId || p.UserId == null) && (session.Groups.Contains(p.GroupId) || p.GroupId == null))
                             orderby p.ObjectId descending, p.UserId descending, p.Permitted, p.GroupId descending
                             select p.Permitted).FirstOrDefault();

        if(!hasPermission)
            throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden", "You do not have permission to access the requested object");
    }

    public int Priority { get { return int.MinValue; } }
}
```

#### Permission Priority:

When the permissions are read from the permission table, the highest priority permission is used to determine if they have access. The more specific the permission entry is, the higher the priority it has when the results are ordered.

- Permissions matching the current user have greater priority than general permissions for all users *i.e where `UserId == null`*. Similarly a permission for the specifically requested object has higher priority than the general permission for that object type.
- User specific permissions take precedence over group permissions. This means, that a user can be granted access by a group permission but be denied access at user level, or vice versa.
- Where the user belongs to a group that allows them access to a resource and to another group that denies them access, then the user will have access.
- The default rule is to deny access.

#### Implementation:

In my example code above I have used this linq query to determine if the user has permission. The example uses a mocked database, and you will need to substitute it with your own provider.

```cs
session.IsAdministrator || 
(from p in Db.Permissions
 where p.ObjectType == objectType && 
     ((p.ObjectId == objectId || p.ObjectId == null) && 
     (p.UserId == session.UserAuthId || p.UserId == null) &&
     (session.Groups.Contains(p.GroupId) || p.GroupId == null))
 orderby p.ObjectId descending, p.UserId descending, p.Permitted, p.GroupId descending
 select p.Permitted).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Custom Session:

I have used a custom session object to store the group memberships, these are looked up and added to the session when the user is authenticated.

```cs
// Custom session handles adding group membership information to our session
public class MyServiceUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public int?[] Groups { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }

    // The int value of our UserId is converted to a string!?! :( by ServiceStack, we want an int
    public new int UserAuthId { 
        get { return base.UserAuthId == null ? 0 : int.Parse(base.UserAuthId); }
        set { base.UserAuthId = value.ToString(); }
    }


    // Helper method to convert the int[] to int?[]
    // Groups needs to allow for null in Contains method check in permissions
    // Never set a member of Groups to null
    static T?[] ConvertArray<T>(T[] array) where T : struct
    {
        T?[] nullableArray = new T?[array.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            nullableArray[i] = array[i];
        return nullableArray;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, ServiceStack.Auth.IAuthSession session, ServiceStack.Auth.IAuthTokens tokens, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        // Determine UserId from the Username that is in the session
        var userId = Db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == session.UserName).Select(u => u.Id).First();

        // Determine the Group Memberships of the User using the UserId
        var groups = Db.GroupMembers.Where(g => g.UserId == userId).Select(g => g.GroupId).ToArray();

        IsAdministrator = groups.Contains(1); // Set IsAdministrator (where 1 is the Id of the Administrator Group)

        Groups = ConvertArray<int>(groups);
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, this, tokens, authInfo);
    }
}
```

I hope you find this example useful. Let me know if anything is unclear.

### Fluent Validation:

> Also, can this be integrated with FluentValidation and return appropriate HTTP responses?

You shouldn't try and do this in the validation handler, because **it is not validation**. Checking if you have permission is a verification process. If you require to check something against a specific value in a datasource you are no longer performing validation. [See this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803929/1295344) which also covers this.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the detailed answer. I've implemented several ideas you suggest.

Firstly, I've taken your approach and used a request filter attribute approach. I've put the attributes on the service classes as I feel that is a more DRY and hence secure location. It was your use of an ObjectId that really pulled it all together for me. I hadn't used custom attributes before so that was a great nugget of new knowledge.  In my approach I've added an extra ObjectAction parameter to allow for different security checks based on what action a user is attempt to do to the given object.

Comment: I already had a service based implementation of object access security which it was very straightforward to tie into the request filter. I've actually made this a first order service, allowing GUI etc to check permissions before providing user interfact elements etc.  I like the implementation details of your ACL pattern, and though its not an exact fit for my project I'm sure I'll try some ideas from it around null wildcards etc.

I do agree authorisation should be outside of validation and I'm very happy to be handling it in my filter and not within the FluentValidation.

Comment: With respect to your comments on validation vs verification, you make an interesting point, but I don't wholely agree with you. I'll expand on my thoughts on this on the question you linked to in due course.

Comment: @richardwhatever Awesome, thanks for the feedback, great to know it helped. Look forward to your thoughts on the validation aspect too :) Good luck with the project. Cheers.

Comment: I like the model here. Will this scale for say a few hundred users and say 10,000 objects? I only ask because that's what I'm after :). Other question, have you used this for filtering lists of accessible objects using SQL, for instance if a user can only access say 10 of the 10,100 objects. If so, would be great to see the SQL for that. Thanks!

Comment: "Where the user belongs to a group that allows them access to a resource and to another group that denies them access, then the user will have access."  An explicit "deny" permission should override an explicit allow.

Comment: @Triynko Entirely depends on your own requirements. The above example is only to demonstrate the ACL pattern with respect to ServiceStack, and the "allow" over "deny" was suitable, as it could still be easily changed to explicit "deny" by changing the sort order in the query to `p.permitted descending`. The comment in the source code explains how sorting is used to prioritise specific permissions. I hope that helps.