# Table designs with lesser load on using with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Planning for an access control module in my project that can handle multiple permissions on different levels. The systems has a superadmin, a admins and users in a hierarchical way. We have certain features, that has to be restricted to some users based on permissions.
I refer a [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22409105/2834139) on this.
According to this answer, I have created a sample table which is like the one below
[image: approach1]

But what makes me worry is, this approach will make the table more and more big. So I tried designing two approaches, which is like the two images below.

[image: approch2]
[image: approch3]

I can't use stored procedures here to evaluate the permissions. So on using entity frame work, which design pattern will give more performance.

Comment: Unless you have millions of rows it won't make any difference.

Comment: Millions of rows if there are proper indexes should no be problematic. That being said, I agree your database is not fully normalized. You should check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @ bradbury9 Thankyou. I used group names for understanding, in reality, that will be ids from the first table. We will be having priomary and foreign keys.