# Override http status code from validator

Tags: c#, servicestack, http-status-codes, fluentvalidation

I've got the following DTO:

```
public class SomethingRequest {
     public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

`Code` must be unique, so I've created a validator that checks if there is already a record with provided code, like the following

```
public class SomethingValidator: AbstractValidator<SomethingRequest> 
{
    public SomethingValidator(ISomethingRepository repo) {
         RuleFor(something => something.Code).Must(BeUnique);
    }

    private bool BeUnique(string code) { ... uniqueness check... }
}
```

As I'm using validation feature, the validator is automatically wired for all methods with `SomethingRequest`, which is really great.

When condition fails I would like to return `409 Conflict` HTTP status code, but `400 Bad Request` is always returned.

So, the questions are:

1. Am I misusing vaidation feature? (i.e. autowired validators were not designed to be used for application logic checks)
2. If I'm not, are there any ways to override `400 BadRequest` status code from validator?

Comment: John have you given my method of using a RequestFilter attribute a try? Would appreciate your feedback, thanks. :)

Comment: @Scott, not yet, I was kind of dragged into some other things. I've got that approach discussed with my colleagues, and we decided it's a way to go, but we are fine with 400 for now and have some more important things to do. Anyway, I'll let you know  :)

Comment: No problem, sorry didn't mean to rush you. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Scott don't worry, no harm done :) Thanks.

Comment: @Scott I end up moving verification in service layer. Filter approach works, but not feasible as requires one filter per request that requires uniqueness check (or common interface, or some other way to extract what to verify).

Comment: Yeah that makes sense if you have lots of verifications to do, then the service layer is a good place. :) Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I misusing validation feature? (i.e. autowired validators were not designed to be used for application logic checks)

I would say this is best done in the business logic away from the validation, because checking for a uniqueness is actually a verification check rather than validation, because it requires checking against a data source. [My answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803929/1295344) addresses a similar concern.

While you can override the response status code of the validation error using the `ErrorResponseFilter`, I would recommend creating your own request filter for this business logic, as overriding the response there will be messy as your application grows, and again, it's not really validation.

Using a filter attribute is straightforward in ServiceStack:

```cs
public class VerifySomethingCodeAttribute : Attribute, IHasRequestFilter
{
    IHasRequestFilter IHasRequestFilter.Copy()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public int Priority { get { return int.MinValue; } }

    public void RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        SomethingRequest somethingRequestDto = requestDto as SomethingRequest;
        if(somethingRequestDto == null)
            return;

        // Verify the code
        // Replace with suitable logic
        // If you need the database your wire it up from the IoC
        // i.e. HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();
        bool isUnique = ...

        if(!isUnique)
            throw HttpError.Conflict("This record already exists");
    }
}
```

Then simply annotate the DTO:

```cs
[VerifySomethingCode]
public class SomethingRequest {
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can be sure that the Code in the DTO will have been verified as unique and you can return any status and response you want. The filter gives you total control.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1) Although it allows dependency injection and wiring up of repositories, the fluent validation code isn't the place you are supposed to put this kind of code as it is more along the lines of verification code. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21803929/459018) has a good explanation of the differences between the two. I'll just add that it also makes sense for splitting the verification up from validation if only for more easily returning the appropriate status code.

2)If you would like to override the `400 BadRequest` status code, you can use the validation feature's `ErrorResponseFilter` like so:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature
{
    ErrorResponseFilter = CustomValidationError
});

...

private object CustomValidationError(ValidationResult validationResult, object errorDto)
{
    var firstError = validationResult.Errors.First();
    return new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, firstError.ErrorCode, firstError.ErrorMessage);
}
```

This filter looks to be intended for a global solution as it doesn't appear to give you any easy way to determine the dto/service the error came from. I would suggest looking at making the change in 1 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As of response filter  - it's kind of overkill, as in reality there're more checks in mentioned validator which does not intent throwing 409.

Comment: Are you able to add this checking in the business logic that you will perform during the service? That way you can hopefully still have the code re-used across the different methods using the dto (assuming some of the business logic is used throughout all methods).